# Google reCaptcha v3 loads v2 API js

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

We are implementing Google reCaptcha v3 and all the setup is done as described [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)

However, when the page loads, I see in browser network that recaptcha__[locale]>.js loads:

1) multiple times (probably 1st time when the api.js is loaded, and the second time when grecaptcha.execute() action performed)
[click to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH8k7.png)

2) loads with API v2 content (the content of that js file is very huge and includes graphic key v2 reCaptcha traces)
[click to see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynFio.png)

Does anybody has any idea how this can be avoided?

I've referenced [the separate page](https://recaptcha-demo.appspot.com/recaptcha-v3-request-scores.php) that has the reCaptcha v3 demo implementation and it has exactly same issues.

Thank you.